# Obfuscation across multiple gradle modules with proguard possible?

Tags: reference, gradle, android-studio, proguard, obfuscation

I have a Gradle project containing the main module and one library module and each one is set up with proguard.

My problem is, that the class which is obfuscated in the library module to "A" or similar is still referenced from the main module with the original name, lets say "MyUtil", which doesn´t exist anymore.

I don´t want to exclude this class from the obfuscation if possible, so is there any way to do obfuscation accross modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved after using

> consumerProguardFiles

in the library project.

Now it works accross modules without doing anything

Comment: Hey i'm facing the same issue, can you please elaborate on how you solved this? I tried to use consumerProguardFiles but the dependency module creates an aar with no obfuscation. I need both modules to be obfuscated together so they can communicate.

Comment: @Fashizel hey. if you want to obfuscate your library, you need to use   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), but if you want to attach proguard rules to your library, which will be recognized by the application which uses your library, you need consumerProguardFiles

Comment: yes, But I end up with one aar (the app) obfuscated and the libraray aar is not. I want to have 2 aar's obfuscated

Comment: ok then consumerProguardFiles should work for you in the library which is currently not obfuscated. try to add verbose to your proguard file to check if everything goes correctly and check if you are using consumerProguardFile in the right build type

Comment: Hey, so i tried to follow all the files generated by proguard and saw that it obfuscating the library and even writes how many classes were reduced. and that the output is in the exploded-aar folder, even there the library is not obfuscated. thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Marian 
I am also facing the same problem, can you please explain exactly how you have solved this using "consumerProguardFiles" ?

Comment: @CRSardar just as you would use "proguardFiles yourconfig". replace that with "consumerProguardFiles yourconfig" or additionally use both, for example if you want to provide the library to public, you only want to keep your API classes that others can work with it, but you want the complete library be obfuscated, if the actual app is builded

Comment: Thanks for quick response,
my case is like this, i have a lib project - A, within that i have two more lib modules B & C, dependencies are as follows - A depends on B, B depends on C & A depends on C
I want expose APIs of only 1 class Utils in A
On compile I am getting - A.arr, B.arr & C.arr
if I do 
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
in each modules, every modules have their own 'proguard-rules.pro' files
then modules getting unresolved dependency errors bcoz of obffescation

Comment: so my requirement is that - A.arr, B.arr & C.arr should be obfuscated, maintaining their inter dependency, that is ClassB in module B which is obfuscated & still being used in module A

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to create a API class in the you library that is excluded from the obfuscation. The API class would just be a facade and call your internal library methods.

Comment: Thank you. This is an approach I didn´t thought of and which really should work at some points. The problem is, that I also communicate with the library by passing objects arround, where your workaround doesn´t really work

Comment: Then exclude the objects too, or as I tend to do obfuscate both main module and library in a single pass / build

Comment: @scottyab, did you manage to do a single pass using gradle? If so, can you share some tips? I'm suffering from each of my modules getting mangled in sequence, so compilation completely breaks.

Comment: @biddster do you have them in the same workspace/project and each library as a module? maybe raise a new question?